# shared images between two applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an admin panel from where I am uploading files to `~/uploads` 
and from Home site I want to access these images path.I have read about `Server.mapPath()` but it is giving me the root path of the current running application. I want to store the absolute path of the images in db so that I can access them from home site.  have read about storing images in db in the form of base 64 but I want to use the file system.
Sorry for incorrect english..

```
path = Path.Combine(
    System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/uploads")),
    image.FileName);
image.SaveAs(path);
```

Comment: I have created two different applications .

Comment: Can you add please some code? And reformulate the question you want to receive an answer.

Comment: path = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/uploads")), image.FileName);
                   
 image.SaveAs(path);

Comment: Edit the question and paste your code there.  Code in comments is unreadable and unhelpful.

Comment: Its from admin side ,stroing the path in db combine with ~/uploading and filename

Comment: If you stored the absolute path into the db, can't you just select the path from the db and use it in the Home site?

Comment: Is there any another way for relative path ?
path i can store in db and the access that from db like 
both application are running on the same server but admin panel as a sub domain.

Answer (score 1):

different scenario different way. If you are using local IIS to host your applications,

1. create a virtual directory "uploads" in your Admin app root with write permission, point to some place, let's say "d:\uploads"
2. create a virtual directory "uploads" in your frontend app root, point to the same place "d:\uploads"
3. modify you uploads codes in your admin app, save the file to `Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/uploads")),
   image.FileName);`
4. store 'Path.Combine("~/uploads/",image.FileName")' to database
5. in front app, use `<img src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/uploads/xxx.jpg")' />` to show the image, if you are using MVC, then no need to use ResolveClientUrl to deal with "~"

if you are using cloud based app, like azure app, then just use azure blob to save your file, also amazon S3 is great and easy to use

if these two apps are hosted on different server, but same subnet, use then you can use path like "\192.168.1.1\uploads" as physical location for the virtual directory, make sure you have the correct credential to access the network driver

if these two apps are not on server and even can not access to each other and any other 3rd server, then you can use dropbox to do the synchronization, set up dropbox on both server, map the virtual directory to an fold under dropbox, the image will be synced to front app right after you saved the file on admin